# C application that copy/moves a file & uses system calls in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm having a hard time making a system call to unlink a file work in my C code. I want to remove the file from the filesystem after the code is copied. I am getting an error that says:

```
declared here extern int unlink (const char *__name) __THROW __nonnull ((1));
```

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char * args [])
{
    int infile, outfile;
    int numofbytesread;
    char buffer[20];

    infile = open(args[1], O_RDONLY, 0700);

    if (infile == ENOENT)
    {
            printf("Could not find file");
            return 1;
    }

    outfile == open(args[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0700);

    while ((numofbytesread = read(infile, buffer, 20))){
            write(outfile, buffer, numofbytesread);
    }
    close(infile);
    close(outfile);

     unlink();
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You didn't explain the issue you're having. Just add unlink (oldfile)? http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Deleting-Files.html

Comment: Don't use JPEG for screenshots, they look ugly. Use PNGs instead. (This is a general advice. But still better is posting text instead of an image.)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Deleting-Files.html

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Please don't answer with a comment, **[edit]** that into your question. And make up your mind whether you are using C **or** C++.

Comment: I updated my posts with my code...I am sorry I didn't know about the img.. Also yes, I am trying to implement unlink at the end of my code and am having difficulty because the error tells me that the parameter that I am trying to pass in, does not match the unlink since it is an int

Comment: `open()` just returns -1 for any error... you need to check `errno` to find out which one.  (so `if (infile == ENOENT)` is incorrect)

Comment: Check `errno` the know the reason. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Deleting-Files.html

Comment: `@ThirupathiThangavel  If he doesn't actually need to parse the reason and handle each reason uniquely then perror will just print the text/reason associated with the last errno returned as shown in my answer.

Comment: Hi compma, I see you're new here, but if you think any answers are good, please upvote them, and please click the √ checkmark next to the one that works for you (solves your problem), to indicate that is the accepted answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Side-note: If you don't include `O_TRUNC` when opening your output file, an existing output file could end up being a mix of the original and new file data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After copying, you can invoke the `unlink` system call.

```
unlink(args[1])
```

But be sure to check if the copy was successful before removing the file.

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Deleting-Files.html

Comment: this helped the error issue thank you!.. I have another question. Is there a way to implement the cp cmd in the code so it just executes the copy cmd and then deletes/unlinks after the copy has been made?     So the only thing that I need to do is run ./filename file1 file2 ?

Comment: @compma: That's what the `mv` command already does in the case where the file must be moved across file systems (it just preserves permissions properly too). Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 3):

If all you're trying to do is call unlink to remove the file, this should work, because `unlink` takes a file path.  Therefore if your input file path is valid and it's not readonly in the file system this should work. I have tested it, and it works for me. It copies the file specified by the first argument to the file specified by the 2nd argument and then deletes the input file.  I also fixed your error handling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    int infile, outfile, readcnt;
    char buffer[20];

    if ((infile = open(args[1], O_RDONLY, 0700)) < 0) {
        perror("Error openning input file");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((outfile = open(args[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0700)) < 0) {
        perror("Error opening output file");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((readcnt = read(infile, buffer, 20)) > 0) {
         if (write(outfile, buffer, readcnt) < 1) {
            perror("Error writing to output file");
            return -1;
         }
    }

    close(infile);
    close(outfile);

    if (unlink(args[1]) < 0) {
        perror("Error unlinking file");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much... this might be a dumb question, but what does retval do? Is there a way to implement the cp cmd in the code so it just executes the copy cmd and then deletes/unlinks after the copy has been made?     So the only thing that I need to do is run ./filename file1 file2 ?

Comment: System calls usually return -1 to indicate error and set errno to the error reason (numeric code).  You can compare things to the error reasons like you did, but if you're not really needing to do specific things for specific reasons, and any failure is fatal, just do `perror()` and exit and it will print the human/text reason for the error.  retval captures the return stat. `read() and `write()` return -1 for error and a positive value if there were bytes written or read.

Comment: See the [perror() man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/perror)

Comment: Great answer. Does `perror` also exit?

Comment: Just compile: `cc -o yourprog yourprog.c`. Then at the command line: `yourprog /path/to/input_file /path/to/output_file`, for example: `yourprog a b` where `./a` has some text in it. And experiment. Make it fail in various ways such as specify non-existent file for a, and see the error, and also create a file b and make have no permissions, like `touch b`, `chmod 000 b` and then youprog a b and there should be an error when you try to open the output file for write because it exists and is unwritable.

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel I might have explained it wrong before, no perror just prints the message.

Comment: @compma I added retval more out of habit. You really only need it if you're *doing* something with the return value (such as for readcnt), otherwise it should be omitted. So I've edited the answer to remove it.

Comment: Last update - I should have returned after each perror(). I fixed that too.